# Nested for loops for validation of input

Tags: python-3.x, validation

I'm new in python and I have a hard time specify what answer I want as valid. I expect input from user for an airport briefing like: LGEL LGTS LGPA LGRP (where these 4 letters is airport identifiers and then a space to go on with the other airport).
I want only characters(no numbers, must accept the spaces though), and after I split the answer to check if this answer has exactly 4 characters. I think my code is close enought but can't make it work

```
answer_list2 = []
answer = input("select aerodromes: ").upper()
answer_list2 = answer.split(' ')
idiot = True
while idiot == True:
    for i in answer_list2:
        for x in i:
            if x.isalpha() == True or x.isspace()== True and len(i) == 4:
                idiot = False
            else:
                print ("I think numbers are not a valid ICAO locator")
                answer = input("---> plz input the aerodromes ")




answer_list = []
answer_list = answer.split(' ')
```

Comment: If the input is wrong, then you can `break` out of the for loop.

Comment: You are meaning the second one wright?

Comment: Yes. The `else` condition

Comment: While statement wont work in this way. I want my program to check all these parameters and keep asking user until valid question.Also something seems bad at my nested for loops.

Comment: I found it. Thx for your help can i improove this ?

Answer (score 0):

```
idiot = True

while idiot:
    answer = input("select aerodromes: ").upper()
    answer_list2 = answer.split(' ')
    for i in answer_list2:
        for x in i:
            if x.isalpha() == True or x.isspace() == True and len(i) == 4:
                idiot = False
            else:
                print ("I think numbers are not a valid ICAO locator")
```

You don't have to ask for input again at the end, if you put it inside the loop.

Comment: Thx for the help in advance.Code must test all the letters to see if there is a number, and each word (after splitted i suppose) to test if all this words has indeed 4 letters.This code still gonna cheat and will go on with the rest of the code if i input eg:EGH LGTS

Comment: You should probably use [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html)

Answer (score 0):

At last i found it ......

```
answer_list2 = []                                                                                        #check input
answer = input("select aerodromes: ").upper()
answer_list2 = answer.split(' ')
ct = 0
while ct != 4*(len(answer_list2)):
    for i in answer_list2:
        for x in i:
            if x.isalpha() == True and len(i) == 4:                                        
                ct += 1
            else:
                print ("Check again your input locators")
                answer_list2 = []
                answer = input("---> plz input the aerodromes ").upper()
                answer_list2 = answer.split(' ')
                break   



answer_list = []
answer_list = answer.split(' ')
```